# /dev/random is not working

Tags: shell, random, linux-kernel, cryptography

I tried to cat the /dev/random. But is just blocks without giving a single byte of output. (Meanwhile the cat of /dev/urandom is working fine).

```
root@test 07:22:08 ~ >cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
36
root@test 07:22:10 ~ >cat /dev/random
```

What could be the possible cause of this ? How to resolve it ?

I am using an embedded system with 2.6 kernel.

Comment: If `/dev/random` blocks for a long time then I wouldn't be confident about the quality of `/dev/urandom`. Embedded devices sometimes do not collect enough entropy to seed `urandom` sufficiently. This is made worse by older kernels being worse as entropy gathering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random):

> When the entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block
>   until additional environmental noise is gathered.

The entropy pool is populated from environmental noise sources such as keyboards. Consequently, if you don't have this source (e.g. in your embedded system or perhaps a headless server) then the entropy pool is empty, and (as noted above) `/dev/random` will block.

Comment: but the pool is not empty. It says 36 bits are available.

Comment: cat is probably buffering some amount.  try wiggling your mouse or whatever (to generate more entropy).

Comment: I tried unbuffered cat also : cat -u /dev/random . I expected ateast a bye of output.

Answer (score 0):

use `/dev/urandom`, its secure

ref: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

When in doubt in early boot, wether you have enough entropy gathered. use `getrandom()` instead. [1]

[1] [git kernel commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c6e9d6f38894798696f23c8084ca7edbf16ee895)

Comment: Normally it is, but on a system where `/dev/random` blocks for a long time for a small request, I have my doubts that `/dev/urandom` is already seeded with enough entropy shortly after boot.

Comment: When in doubt save some random numbers after you know you have seen _some_ entropy, and use that as seed on the next boot. (most distros do exactly this).  A fallback to /dev/random usually is usually _not_ a good idea. That blocks and that means some service is not working (in time).

Comment: Saving random data isn't reliable either. One problem is that it's the same for cloned virtual machines. The second problem is that you can't reliably delete data from an SSD, so you won't achieve forward secrecy since and attacker might be able to recover the continuation key from the disk.

Comment: In recent versions of linux, the `getrandom()` system call should be the best approach. AFAIK it blocks until at least 128 bits of entropy have been gathered after boot but then outputs arbitrary amounts of secure data, similar to `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Ah sounds like the winner! - `getrandom()`.  Thats how `/dev/urandom` should have been implemented too. (That would even have eliminated the (confusing) existence of two random devices).